# How do you check if an object is an instance of a generic type in JAVA?

Tags: java, class, object, oop, casting

so i need to write a method called frequency to calculate the number of occurances of an Object of type E in a collection ( i'm not even sure if the collection  should be a linked list like i did  or if i should've just called the constructor `super()`, i just thought that if i didn't make it a linkedlist then what's the point of naming the class linkedlistcollection) , this method takes a parameter of type Object , i can't change that cuz that's the contract, here is the code :

```
public class LinkedListCollection<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {
     
      private int size;
      private Collection<? extends E > list;
     /**
     * @ensures isEmpty();
     */
    public LinkedListCollection() {
      list = new LinkedList<>();
      size = 0;
    }

    /**
 
     *
     * @param is the Collection of elements that should be placed in the list
     *
     * @requires c != null;
     * @requires !c.contains(null);
     * @ensures containsAll(c) && c.containsAll(this);
     * @ensures size() == c.size();
     *
     * @throws NullPointerException is the param collection is null or  contains null
     */
    public LinkedListCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
      if ((c == null) || (c.contains(null))  )
     { 
        throw new NullPointerException();
     } 
        list=new LinkedListCollection<>();
        size=c.size();
        list.addAll(c);

    }
```

and then there's what i did in the frequency method

```
public int frequency(Object o) {
        E newob= (E) o;
        Iterator it = list.iterator();
        int frequency= 0;
        while(it.hasNext())
       {
         if (it.next().equals(newob))
         frequency++;
       } 
       return frequency;

    }
```

now to calculate the frequency i wanted to check if the object is an instance of E first, but isinstanceof doesn't work with generic types, so i just performed a cast like you can see above, i'm not convinced this is the right thing to do tho. What's the correct way of coding this method? are my constructors correct? and how do we check if object is an instance of a generic type ? ( i believe it's also needed to redefine `equals`)
thank you!

Comment: Irrespective of the issue of checking whether something is an `E`, you're invoking the constructor of `LinkedListCollection` inside the constructor of `LinkedListCollection`. You don't want to do that.

Comment: Why not just use `Collections.frequency`?

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to check whether something is an instance of `E`? If `o` is an instance of `E`, it might be found in the list, and so its frequency will be 0 or more; if `o` isn't an instance of `E`, it won't be found in the list (barring heap pollution problems), and so its frequency will be 0.

Comment: @AndyTurner can i use collections.frequency on a linked list without extending the collections class?

Comment: In addition of all what @AndyTurner said already in his comments: replace the line with the equals check: `if( it.next().equals( o )`, remove the cast, and you are set. The cast will only work, when `o` *is* an instance of `E`, it will not be made to one by the cast. And the usual implementation of `equals()` always tests first, if the instances do have the same type.

Comment: As said, you don't even need the cast. You're doing nothing with `newob` except passing it to the `equals` method, which already accepts `Object`. Right now, the cast will not even do anything at runtime, since type erasure changes this to a cast to `Object`.

Comment: @10969_shirazu_ of course you can. You just invoke the method. Please rid yourself of the notion that the only way you can (or should) accomplish things in Java (and other languages) is via inheritance.

Comment: @tquadrat "The cast will only work, when o is an instance of E" depends on what you mean by "work": it's an unchecked cast, so it will always succeed; it just won't actually check if it's an instance of E.